# Difference between addSubview: and insertSubview:atIndex:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When adding subviews to a `UIView`, what's the difference between the methods `addView:` and `insertView:atIndex:`?

Comment: You don't provide enough detail to answer your question. Do you mean UIView's addSubview and insertSubview:atIndex: ?

Answer (score 17):

Both add a view to the receiver as a subview, which causes the view to be displayed if the receiver is displayed and positioned relative to the receiver.

But,

- `addSubview:` adds your view to the end of the subview list, which places it on top of the other subviews when drawing.
- `insertSubview:atIndex:` adds your view at a particular position in the list, which places it above the subviews that come before it in the list, and below the subviews that come afterward.

`[parentView addSubview:childView]` is the same as `[parentView insertSubview:childView atIndex:[[parentView subviews] count]]`.

Everything you need to know is [here](https://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Answer (score 1):

AddView adds a view to an array of views.

InsertView adds a view into a specific position in an array.

Other than that, check the Documentation.